# Ubuntu 14.04:Export mysql database failed with command line

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vagrant

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Vagrant, And I want to export the database with mysql command line,But always failed with this message:

you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u root -p hockey_development>/home/jason/Documents/Projects/hockey_development1.sql'

I think there is no problems in this command line and the database;

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFL23.png)

Comment: run mysqldump as a command  not as a mysql query.

Comment: Got it,Thank you Peeyush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqldump` is a command meant to be run directly from the command line -- not while logged into mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Using mysqldump, you can backup a local database using a single command.

backup: # `mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql`

Source: [Backup and Restore MySQL Database Using mysqldump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)